# How can I make my specs run faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have several spec files that look like the following:

```
describe "My DSL" do

  before :each do
    @object = prepare_my_object
  end

  describe "foo" do

    before :each do
      @result = @object.read_my_dsl_and_store_stuff_in_database__this_is_expensive
    end

    it "should do this" do
      @result.should be_this
    end

    it "should not do that" do
      @result.should_not be_that
    end

    # ... several more tests about the state of @result
  end

  # ...
end
```

These tests take a long time, essentially because the second `before :each` block runs every time. Using `before :all` instead does not really help, because it gets called before the outer `before :each`. Putting all expectations in one single `it` block would help, but this is considered bad style.

What is best practice to have my expensive method being executed only once?

Comment: Can you just put `prepare_my_object` in an `:all` block too?

Comment: I thought of that, but this will conflict with the other tests (not shown here).

Comment: *this will conflict with the other tests* in what way?

Comment: It will conflict with the other tests in that file, that depend on the first `before :each`. My conclusion after I asked this question and thought more about it, is to tailor-fit this part of my specs. A `before :all` block will then be part of the solution. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to speed up rspec is to completely decouple the database. The *DSL* problem is a different problem from the *get stuff in to and out of a db* problem. If you have one method doing both, is it is possible to break the method into pieces?

Ideally, your DSL would be cached locally, so it wouldn't have to be pulled from the db on every request anyway. It could get loaded once in memory and held there before refreshing.

If you run against a local, in-memory cache, and decouple the db, does that speed things up? If yes, then it's the db call that's slow. If your DSL is completely loaded up in memory and the tests are still slow, then the problem is your DSL itself.

Comment: Thank you. My DSL is computed by a third party gem and this is the suggested way to test custom DSLs. What I would like best, is to have a `before :all` that runs inside the `describe` block after the outer `before :each` block. Something like that.